# Cut, Copy and Paste for Node-WebKit app doesn't work in OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, node-webkit

I have created a Node-Webkit app for chat. For windows and linux, cut, copy and paste commands are working fine. But the same is not working in OSX.

Please help me solving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this? https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Clipboard

Comment: No. 'cmd+A' , 'cmd+C' , 'cmd+X' and 'cmd+V' are not working

Comment: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Shortcut - there is a manual here on key shortcuts, too.  I haven't implemented this in my app yet, so I don't have a ready example for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the native OSX edit menu for copy and paste to work properly. This should do the trick:

```
// initialize window menu
var win = gui.Window.get(),
    nativeMenuBar = new gui.Menu({
        type: "menubar"
    });

// check operating system for the menu
if (process.platform === "darwin") {
    nativeMenuBar.createMacBuiltin("Your App Name");
}

// actually assign menu to window
win.menu = nativeMenuBar;
```

Further reading on [menus in Node-Webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Menu).